# Keras set_learning_phase for Dropout when saving TensorFlow Session

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, keras, keras-layer

I have been following [this post](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html), in particular part II, to use Keras as an interface to TensorFlow.

As an example I have been training a CNN using the MNIST data set. My aim is to train and evaluate a model in a TF session then save the session using `tf.train.Saver()` so that I can deploy the model on CloudML.

I am able to do this for a model which does not use Dropout, however, when I include Dropout layers in Keras you need to specify the learning_phase (training = 1, testing = 0), this is done through the feed_dict (see code below).

Locally I am able to control this by doing something like

```
test_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={images: mnist_data.test.images, labels: mnist_data.test.labels, K.learning_phase(): 0})
```

However when I upload my model to CloudML and try to test I get the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
     [[Node: keras_learning_phase = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I know it is because of the line in the feed_dict but I have no idea how to get around it. In the blog post section IV it talks about this problem in the context of TensorFlow serving where the model is loaded and re-saved. I couldn't get this to work for my approach because I need to export the session export and export.meta, not the Keras model.

```
# Make a session in tf
sess = tf.Session()
# sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Register the tf session with Keras
K.set_session(sess)

# Generate placeholders for the images and labels and mark as input.
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))
keys_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None,))
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10))
inputs = {'key': keys_placeholder.name, 'image': images.name}
tf.add_to_collection('inputs', json.dumps(inputs))

# To be able to extract the id, we need to add the identity function.
keys = tf.identity(keys_placeholder)

# Define a simple network
# Two fully-connected layer with 128 units and ReLU activation
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.50))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
preds = model(images) # Output

# Define some Ops
prediction = tf.argmax(preds ,1)
scores = tf.nn.softmax(preds)

# Use the Keras caterforical crossentropy_function and the tf reduce mean
loss = tf.reduce_mean(categorical_crossentropy(labels, preds))
# Define the optimizer
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
# Initialization op
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
# Saver op
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Mark the outputs.
outputs = {'key': keys.name,
           'prediction': prediction.name,
           'scores': scores.name}
tf.add_to_collection('outputs', json.dumps(outputs))

# Get the data
mnist_data = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True, reshape=False)

# Open session
with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(init_op)
    # print keras_learning_phase.eval()

    for i in range(100):
        batch = mnist_data.train.next_batch(50)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={images: batch[0],
                                  labels: batch[1],
                                  K.learning_phase(): 1})
    saver.save(sess, 'test/export')
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a very Keras oriented programming issue, it would be best to post this question directly to their GitHub [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues).

You can also find that [this same issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2310) was reported & solved [many times](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keras_learning_phase) in their Issue Tracker already. The solution to your issue might also be covered in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).